# How to decrypt the password generated by wordpress

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I am using a wordpress site. I just want to know , How to get a plain text from encrypted password(stored in wordpress database). I used the `$wp_hasher->CheckPassword($plain_password, $password_hashed)` to check the password is correct or not. But this time i would like to know  how to get plain text.

Comment: So, you want the password that is entered? I don't know if it's safe for your users if you know their passwords in plain text...

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? -1.

Comment: @iyrag I am creating a mobile app in which a user can update his password any number of times, or The user may wish to email the password that he  created. Any way i just wanted to know how it looks like but not intended to know my user's password and change them. right

Comment: Instead of sending the password that he entered, just generate a new one and send it by email.

Comment: http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/09/wordpress-password-hash-generator/ this one helps you to decrypt a password

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will not be able to retrieve a plain text password from wordpress.

Wordpress use a 1 way encryption to store the passwords using a variation of md5. There is no way to reverse this.

See this article for more info http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-is-the-user-password-encrypted-wp_hash_password

Answer (score 25):

This is one of the proposed solutions found in the [article](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-decode-wordpress-password-hash) Jacob mentioned, and it worked great as a manual way to change the password without having to use the email reset.

1. In the DB table `wp_users`, add a key, like **abc123** to the
   `user_activation` column.
2. Visit yoursite.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=**abc123**&login=**yourusername**
3. You will be prompted to enter a new password.

Comment: Not working, says "Your password reset link has expired. Please request a new link below"

Comment: This method still works but I had to be sure to leave both `user_pass` and `user_activation` null or empty and then when I went to **yoursite.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=&login=yourusername** I just left the `key=` just like that in the URL blank, and then it sent over the email to me to click on and create a new password. So I believe those are the keys to get it to work for those with trouble in conjunction with ensuring the `user_email` valid email address that will not block the email when it sends a password reset link.