# how can i get the users list and password from wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

i have changed my website from wordpress to simple php now i want to get all the usernames and password that have signed up on my wordpress website in a simple list that includes only username list and password can anyone help me with this... 
I am getting this type of passwords may be encrypted $P$B4UyLRqMCFyRSpLpePHVKCCDrt8b1A0

need to decrypt and see simple list

Thanks Regards

Comment: Well how do you want the passwords? A simple query like select username,password from wp_users?

Comment: @shiv i am getting $P$B4UyLRqMCFyRSpLpePHVKCCDrt8b1A0 these types of passwords

Comment: If you want them decrypted it just won't happen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457301/how-to-decrypt-the-password-generated-by-wordpress

Comment: Just use the encoded passwords from the wordpress site by using the same encoding method Wordpress uses.